# CSS | why does the linear gradient do have slides when the direction is set top/bottom?

Tags: css

why does the linear gradient do have slides when the direction is set top/bottom ? if i set it to right or left it doesn't show slides .. should i set the width to 100% ? or make it auto .. the problem here is that when i tried to use the "deg" instead of using to bottom the code didn't run

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/lolpizo/pen/KKaWzjY)

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-logo">ON ANIME</div>
        <div class="header-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">url</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">url</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">url</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="search-bar"><button>Buy now</button></div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://fr.techtribune.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/boruto-chapter-55.jpg"/>
            <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
      
    
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
```

```js
* {
    outline: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
   /* background-image:
    url('https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/34-345522_all-anime-characters-wallpaper-hd.jpg');
    background-size: cover; */

   /* background-image: 
              linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(
                145, 146, 122, 0.62), rgba(
                  217, 91, 132, 0.58)), url(
'https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/34-345522_all-anime-characters-wallpaper-hd.jpg'); */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.548), rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.555)),
url(https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/34-345522_all-anime-characters-wallpaper-hd.jpg)

;
background-size: cover;

} 


header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(22, 22, 48);
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00000094;
}

.header-links ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header-links ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.header-logo {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.search-bar {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
} 

.container {
    width: 93%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(77, 77, 201, 0.781);

}

div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 12px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px black;
    transition: transform .5s ease;


}
img {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 3%;
    border-top-right-radius: 3%;
}
.caption {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #232223;
}

div.item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css. The height of your html and body is not getting the whole height of the page size.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: i didn't really think about that .. silly me thank youu for the tip ♥

Comment: @ZUPPALOL Useful tip: 
If you want to debug your elements or styles with regards to their height, width, color or etc... Just use inspect element for you to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try different options to set the height.

```
html,body{
height: 100vh;
```

}

Comment: yup someone else sloved it for me <3 thank youu